# ¿Cuál es el chiste más antiguo escrito en español?

Tags: historia, literatura

Trasteando en el CORDE me encontré con este texto:

> *Yendo dos señoras por la calle, la una de ellas que se decía Castañeda, soltósele un trueno bajero, a lo cual dijo la otra:
>
>       —Niña, pápate esa castaña.
>
>       Echándose de ellos por tres veces arreo, y respondiendo la otra lo mismo, volviéronse y vieron un doctor en medicina que les venía
>   detrás, y, por saber si había habido sentimiento del negocio,
>   dijéronle:
>
>       —Señor, ¿ha rato que nos sigue?
>
>       Respondió:
>
>       —De la primera castaña, señoras.*
>
> Juan de Timoneda, "Buen aviso y portacuentos", España (1564)

Este relato corto, uno de los muchos del libro mencionado, es lo que hoy conocemos como un [chiste](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8uGDUv7): "Dicho u ocurrencia agudos y graciosos." Los chistes suelen ser breves, expresados en unas pocas frases (aunque hay excepciones). Por tanto, no estoy buscando aquí diálogos humorísticos presentes en comedias, sino relatos breves, no insertados en obras más largas, que puedan constituir un chiste por sí mismo sin formar parte de un contexto más grande. Y por breve me refiero a relatos que puedan ser repetidos de memoria y de forma íntegra por cualquier persona con simplemente ser oídos una vez.

Así pues, ¿cuál podría ser considerado el chiste más antiguo escrito en español?

Por tratar de centrar un poco el tiro, en la Wikipedia se comenta [lo siguiente](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiste):

> En España, las primeras compilaciones de chistes se encuentran en el género renacentista de las misceláneas del siglo XVI y XVII, de ámbito especialmente cortesano, destacando en especial Pero Mexía [1497-1551], quien los agrupó por temas, entre muchos otros entre los que cabe mencionar a Juan Timoneda [1518-1583]. Algunos poetas cultivaron especialmente este tipo de divertimentos cortesanos, como por ejemplo Baltasar del Alcázar [1530-1606].

El ejemplo que encontré es precisamente de Juan de Timoneda. Luego, y salvo que algún escritor publicara algún chiste suelto intercalado en alguna obra mayor, básicamente habría que mirar cuál es la primera de esas compilaciones.

Comment: Puede contribuir a la discusión el [Libro de los Gatos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libro_de_los_gatos). No está concebida como humorística, pero abunda en un humor cándido, según recuerdo

Comment: Depende de como defines "un chiste" y "español"...  Ninguno de estos términos esta 100% definido sin ambiguidad.

Comment: @Paul he intentado definir lo que es un chiste en el planteamiento de la pregunta. Y por español podemos tomar cualquier texto escrito a partir del Cantar del Mío Cid.

Comment: ¿Que tan corto hay que ser para que sea "un chiste" y no una obra "mas larga"?

Comment: Como se distingue entre lo "gracioso" y lo que no lo es?

Comment: @Paul un chiste de hace siglos no tiene por qué ser gracioso ahora, lo que cuenta es la intención humorística con la que se escribió. Te adjunto [un enlace](http://www.abc.es/archivo/20150122/abci-chistes-antiguos-historia-201501211940.html) con una recopilación de los chistes más antiguos del mundo localizados hasta ahora. Eso, junto con el ejemplo que pongo en la pregunta, te puede dar una idea de lo que se puede considerar un chiste.

Comment: @Paul en todo caso, creo que no es necesario que definamos perfectamente lo que se considera un chiste. Si tienes alguna respuesta que proponer, hazlo y en caso de duda podemos debatir entre todos si es correcta o no. Como hacemos siempre, vamos.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48811/discussion-between-paul-and-carlos-alejo).

Comment: *Las batamantas*

Comment: La verdad es que es difícil encontrar el chiste más antiguo escrito en español. La publicación de cualquier escrito era algo costoso y no se gastaban el dinero en publicar chistes. Si me parece interesante cuándo comenzó a ser la imprenta lo suficientemente "barata" para que alguien escribiese y se publicara un chiste.

Comment: @walen, si tienes un "candidato" considera por favor incluirlo en una respuesta. Yo lo dejaría ahí en plan "candidato no oficial" y si luego van apareciendo más que lo "mejoren" (se puedan considerar chistes/chanzas de la época en escritos más antiguos a los de las respuestas existentes) el OP debería actualizar la selección de respuesta aceptada. Es muy difícil proponer en este caso una "respuesta definitiva y segura de fuentes oficiales", así que yo iría dejando "lo mejor que tenemos hasta el momento" e incluyendo nuevas respuestas según lleguen o se descubran.

Comment: Relacionado en [mythology.se]: [What is the world's oldest joke?](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/q/3373)

Answer (score 9):

> *VN tamborinero tenía una mujer tan contraria a su opinión que nunca cosa que le rogara podía acabar con ella que la hiziesse.
>
>   Una vez, yendo de un lugar para otro porque havía de tañer en unos desposorios, y ella cavallera en un asno con su tamborino encima, al passar de un río díxole: "Muger, catad no tangáys el tamborino, que se espantará el asno." Como si dixera "tañedlo": en ser en el río sonó el tamborino, y el asno, espantándose, púsose en el hondo, y echó vuestra muger en el río. Y él, por bien que quiso ayudalle, no tuvo remedio.
>
>   Viendo que se havía ahogado, fuela a buscar el río arriba. Díxole uno que lo estava mirando: "Buen hombre, ¿qué buscáys?" Respondió: "A mi muger, que se es ahogada, señor." "¿Y contrario la havéys de buscar?" Dixo: "Sí, señor, porque mi muger siempre fue contraria a mis opiniones."*

Este es el primer cuento del ***Sobremesa y alivio de caminantes***, editado en **1563**. Es una de las primeras obras de Juan de Timoneda, un año anterior al *Buen avíso y portacuentos* mencionado por OP, y se puede consultar en formato HTML [en este enlace](http://parnaseo.uv.es/Lemir/Textos/Sobremesa/Libro1a.htm).

Creo que estaremos todos de acuerdo en que es un texto gracioso y, de hecho, muestra todas las características de un chiste (una introducción, un tono desenfadado, la gracia final que induce a risa) según se describen en Wikipedia.

No pretendía publicar esto como respuesta, dado que OP indica que los primeros recopilatorios de chistes serían (de nuevo según Wikipedia) los hechos por Pero Mexía medio siglo antes:

> En España, las primeras compilaciones de chistes se encuentran en el género renacentista de las misceláneas del siglo XVI y XVII, de ámbito especialmente cortesano, **destacando en especial Pero Mexía [1497-1551], quien los agrupó por temas**

Decidido a encontrar dichas compilaciones, me he estado leyendo por encima las principales obras del tal [Pero Mexía](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedro_Mej%C3%ADa): principalmente la *[Silua de varia lecion](https://archive.org/details/silvadevarialecc00mex)* de 1540, y los *[Coloquios o dialogos](http://alfama.sim.ucm.es/dioscorides/consulta_libro.asp?ref=B23379121&idioma=0)* de 1545. Ambas tratan temas relativamente serios (filosofía, ciencia, religión) y no he notado tono jocoso en los fragmentos que he leído. Doy por hecho que la *Historia del emperador Carlos V* y la *Historia imperial y cesarea*, del mismo autor, también son serias.
El caso es que **no he encontrado entre los textos de Pero Mexía ningún recopilatorio de chistes, mucho menos por temas**.

De ser cierto esto último, entonces el *Sobremesa y alivio de caminantes* de Juan de Timoneda sería posiblemente el primer recopilatorio de chistes impreso en español, y su "Cuento primero" el primer chiste.

Comment: Es verdad que los textos de Pedro Mexía son bastante serios pero hay un chiste bastante [antiguo](http://eljuanperez.blogspot.com.es/2017/04/el-gemelo-del-cesar.html) que Pedro Mexía recoge en *Silva de varia leccion*, concretamente en el capítulo XL de la primera parte. Posiblemente de ahí y quizá alguna otra anécdota similar vengan las referencias a recopilaciones de chistes de ese autor.

Comment: Me parece una respuesta acertada y una investigación correcta. El hecho de que en la pregunta me hubiera quedado cerca de la respuesta no era motivo para no publicar dicha respuesta, me alegra que lo hayas hecho. :-)

Comment: Lo había encontrado ya, antes de comentar quería asegurarme que estaba. Aunque más que una respuesta podría ser un añadido en la tuya ¿cómo lo ves?

Comment: Ok. Cuando tenga un rato intentaré darle forma de respuesta

Answer (score 6):

Entre los que se consideran los chistes más antiguos hay uno que se cree tiene unos 2000 años, hay varias versiones que han aparecido en distintos libros a lo largo del tiempo, esta una de ellas (el original es en latín):

> Aquel hombre, en cambio, que todo el mundo en Sicilia estaba de
>   acuerdo en que era sumamente parecido al gobernador de la provincia,
>   era de espíritu insolente. En efecto,como el procónsul le dijera que
>   le asombraba que fuera tan parecido a él, dado que su padre nunca
>   había venido a Sicilia, aquél replicó: “Pero el mío sí que fue a
>   Roma”. Con esta broma vengó la castidad ultrajada de su madre
>   arrojando, a su vez, la sospecha sobre la madre de aquel, con más
>   audacia de la que convenía en alguien sometido a las varas y segures.

<sub>Hechos y dichos memorables - *Valerio Máximo*</sub> 



Pedro Mexía también recogió esta anécdota, ya traducida al español, en su libro *Silva de varia lecion* (1540), otros lo hicieron después. Este es el fragmento:

> También le pasó a Octaviano César otra graciosa cosa con un mancebo
>   que vino a Roma en el tiempo en que él imperaba en ella. Fue ésta: que
>   vino a Roma un mancebo que parecía tanto al mismo Octaviano en el
>   gesto, que a maravilla era mirado por todos; y siendo avisado de esto
>   Octaviano, luego lo hizo traer ante sí, donde se notó y certificó más
>   la grande similitud que había entre ellos. El emperador, como era de
>   dulce conversación y se preciaba de decir algunas veces cosas agudas y
>   graciosas, viendo que todos decían que le parecía mucho, le dijo al
>   mancebo: “Dime, hermano, ¿vino tu madre alguna vez a Roma?” El mozo
>   entendió la malicia y respondióle: “Mi madre, señor, nunca vino a
>   Roma; pero mi padre vino muchas veces”, motejándole a él de lo que él
>   había sido tocado.

<sub>Se puede consultar aquí: https://archive.org/stream/silvadevarialecc00mex#page/112/mode/2up</sub>



No sé si en el libro habrá más historias de este tipo, como dice @walen los temas son bastante serios y por lo que el propio Pedro Mexía dice no parece muy dado a hablar de temas vulgares:

> Por lo qual yo, preciándome tanto de la lengua que aprendí de mis
>   padres como de la que me mostraron preceptores, quise dar estas
>   vigilias a los que no entienden los libros latinos, y ellos
>   principalmente quiero que me agradezcan este trabajo, pues son los más
>   y los que más necessidad y desseo suelen tener de saber estas cosas.
>   Porque yo, cierto, *he procurado hablar de materias que no fuessen muy
>   comunes ni anduviesen por el vulgo, o que ellas, de si, fuessen
>   grandes y provechosas*, a lo menos a mi  juyzio.

Es difícil afirmar categóricamente que es el primer chiste escrito en español pero por lo que sabemos, si no lo es, se le acerca bastante.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:**

Según la Wikipedia [Hechos y dichos memorables](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hechos_y_dichos_memorables) (*Factorum ac dictorum memorabilium*) se tradujo al español por primera vez en 1395. Si esto es así, el chiste ya estaba escrito en español 145 años antes del libro de Pedro Mexía, aunque sigue siendo el mismo chiste.

---

Parte de la información la he sacado de aquí:
[Un chiste actual de hace 2.000 años](http://es.antiquitatem.com/chistes-antiguos-facetiae-apothegma)