# ¿Tienen las palabras chiste, chisme y chistar una etimología común?

Tags: etimología

En [¿Cuál es el chiste más antiguo conocido escrito en español?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/18712/cu%C3%A1l-es-el-chiste-m%C3%A1s-antiguo-conocido-escrito-en-espa%C3%B1ol/19428?noredirect=1#comment29091_19428) se pregunta específicamente sobre el primer relato gracioso  que se escribió en el idioma español. Pero, en el sigio XVI, el significado de la palabra chiste no implicaba un relato gracioso.

Para el siglo XVI, la palabra **chiste** es muy cercana a chisme.

> La carta que me escribiste agora bien parecía ser del urdimbre de vuestro juicio y de la estofa ... religioso, y aun de los muy observantes, de san Francisco, me metáis agora en chistes de amores y me empadronéis con los muy enamorados. (1539)

Otros textos que refieren la palabra chiste en el s.XIII, son cuentos o anécdotas sin necesidad de tener un carácter gracioso. P. ej, [Glosa del romance sobre el saco de Roma. El chiste de la monja: contrahecho a lo espiritual. Un mote muy sentido](https://books.google.com.mx/books?id=Twn-O95qR0UC&dq=%22chiste%22&hl=es&source=gbs_navlinks_s)  (1501)

Y en el siglo XIII se usaba con una connotación negativa:

> más vale digan esso que **chistas** e locuras

La definición más antigua de las tres palabras que encontre aparece en: [Tesoro de la lengua castellana o española](https://books.google.com.mx/books?id=YsRKAAAAcAAJ&dq=%22chisme%22&hl=es&source=gbs_navlinks_s) (1611)

**Chisme**- Y chismería. Chismoso que va con nuevas de otro de cosas que debiera callar por habérsela fiado y dicha en perjuicio de la person a quien lo revela que ha de tomar a disgusto. Dicha con malicia para revolver y causar diferencias.
**Chistar**- Querer empezar a hablar. Los que estan escondidos no han ni aun de chistar; que es echar aliento con algún espíritu o sonido.
 **Chiste**- Vale donaire. Estos chistes le tienen cuando se dicen con mucha agudeza y pocas palabras, como a la oreja. Del sonido chis chis.

El único análisis etimológico extendido que se ofrece es el de **chisme**

**τρισμος**, murmurar
**γογγυσμος**, tambien murmurar
**σχίσμα**, discordia
Del árabe **gisme**, o pequeña que se pone sobre la letra q.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Según el DRAE, que sin duda habrás consultado, tanto *chiste* como *chistar* son de origen onomatopéyico, mientras que *chisme* proviene del latín *schisma* y éste del griego *σχίσμα* "discordia" (que dio también el término culto *cisma*). De manera que no parece haber origen común.

Sin embargo, el parecido fonético entre los términos puede haber reforzado cierta afinidad de significado, es decir, haber fomentado una etimología folclórica que analice ambos términos como cognados y los reinterprete como tales. A fin de cuentas, tanto un chiste como un chisme suelen ser cosas falsas o distorsionadas destinadas a reírse, burlarse o desprestigiar a otra persona.

Como nota en apoyo de esta idea podría mencionar que en Argentina se dice *chusmear* a la acción de entrometerse para escuchar o espiar o ser testigo de algo que uno no debería, y *chusmo/a* se usa a veces como adjetivo para designar a quien escucha lo que no debe y lo propaga aun sin saber si es cierto, es decir, una persona chismosa. Aquí se han emparentado por analogía dos palabras que no tienen relación etimológica alguna (*chusma* significa originalmente la tripulación de remeros de una galera y viene del griego *κέλευσμα* que designaba al canto acompasado con el cual se marcaba el ritmo a los galeotes), ayudado por el hecho de que la moderna acepción de *chusma* implica malos modales o baja educación.