# ¿Cuál es el refrán o dicho más antiguo escrito en castellano?

Tags: español-medieval, modismos, refranes

Ya alguna vez charlie preguntaba por el [chiste más antiguo en español](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/18712/cu%C3%A1l-es-el-chiste-m%C3%A1s-antiguo-escrito-en-espa%C3%B1ol). Oyendo de refranes en estos días me preguntaba acerca de cual podría ser el primer refrán o dicho en castellano y si bien prefiero el término español, ante posibles respuestas como Eureka, o Vine, vi y vencí... no serían muy apropiadas, ni Arquímides ni Julio Cesar sabrían mucho de lo que sería España y de su futura lengua... pero esa es otra discusión. Si bien [el Conde Lucanor](https://es.wikisource.org/wiki/Conde_Lucanor) de Don Juan Manuel parecería la primera fuente de dichos, no sé si existan otras obras similares o si apliquen como *refranes* propiamente las moralejas del conde.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Difícil veo yo localizar el primer refrán en español, porque refranes como tales, y antes que estos los proverbios, los hay desde tiempos antiguos. Recordemos que en la Biblia hay un libro llamado de los proverbios. Sin embargo, podemos intentar buscar en el CORDE algunos ejemplos de estos en español antiguo.

Buscando por *refrán* aparece lo siguiente:

> *Et oy dezir a Alfonso Garçia et a otros omnes de casa del infante don Manuel, mio padre, que biniera estonçes a Niebla atener frontera contra don Anrique, su hermano, et avn entonçe, por que el rey de Aragon non touo el pleito que puso con don Anrique, fizieron vn cantar de que me non acuerdo sinon del refran, que dize:*
>
> *Rey bello, que Deo confonda, tres son estas con a de Malonda.*
>
> Juan Manuel, *Libro de las armas*, p 1335 (España).

En este caso *refrán* hace referencia al estribillo de la canción o *cantar* que se menciona, a su frase más repetida, que al final hace las veces de moraleja, lo que se espera que la gente recuerde (como si fuera un verdadero adagio o refrán). Si buscamos por *proverbio* entonces podemos llegar más atrás:

> *Como diz' el proverbio que non ha encubierta
>
> que en cabo de cosa a mal non se revierta,
>
> supo por otras partes Alexandre la çierta,
>
> parçir non ge la quiso por boz nin por refierta.*
>
> Anónimo, *Libro de Alexandre*, 1240-1250 (España).

Y otro:

> *Como diz el proverbio que fabla por raçón,
>
> que el romero fito éssi saca ración,
>
> valióli a Semena la firme oración,
>
> e que fo porfidiosa en la su petición.*
>
> Gonzalo de Berceo, *Vida de Santo Domingo de Silos*, c 1236 (España).

No encuentro textos anteriores a estos, que se encuentran casi en el límite de lo que está registrado en el CORDE.

El refrán al que se refiere este último texto se encuentra en textos como:

- Romero fito siempre saca çatico.
- Romero fito assi saca raçion.
- Demandava limosnas como romero fito.

Con *fito* se refiere a "fijo", "sin mudarse a ningún lugar". Y *çatico* sería "cacho, pedazo". El romero fijo saca cacho, tajada. El que es importuno y tiene perseverancia alcanza casi lo que se propone. El equivalente antiguo a "el que la sigue la consigue". El origen del refrán estaría en que muchas veces se da dinero a un mendigo más por su insistencia que por caridad, cosa que suele pasar con las personas que reparten romero a los viandantes (aquí en Sevilla se solían ver con frecuencia por las inmediaciones de la catedral).

Puedes consultar el libro *Seniloquium: Refranes que dizen los viejos* para más información sobre este y otros refranes antiguos, de Diego García de Castro.

Comment: Trato de buscar en la pregunta una sentencia 'propia' del español medieval que pueda reconocerse en el habla cotidiana, pero me has dado una buena pista de la que debió ser la tarea inicial (buscar antes de preguntar)

Comment: @VeAqui te he ampliado un poco la respuesta, ahondando en el último ejemplo.

Comment: En el ejemplo del *Libro de las armas*, *refrán* significa *estribillo*, por lo que no sirve para nuestro caso.

Comment: @Gorpik you're absolutely right, sir. No había caído en el uso de _refrán_ como en el francés _refrain_ (que dio origen también al inglés _refrain_), con el significado de "frase recurrente en poemas o canciones". Y precisamente el texto habla de un "cantar".

Comment: @Charlie mil gracias.  Vale aportar el libro de Apolonio que dice 'Como dice el proverbio, que suele retrayer, que la copdicia mala saco suele romper' (la ambición rompe el saco, en español moderno) o los refraneros como Los Refranes que dizen las viejas tras el fuego (ya 3 siglos después)